# Multiple buttons with different values and a click counter

Tags: javascript, html, database

I currently have a project going on and I was wondering how to make a counter that increases as clicked. All the buttons would have different values (such as 2) and once clicked, the counter would increase. I currently have all the buttons set up but I'm not sure how to add value to them and have a counter increase according to the amount that button is worth. I also wanted to know how I could store that value on the web cache. If anyone could help, I'd be really thankful. Here is the current code I have.

```css
    body{
     background-color: #162428;
    }
    .button {
        background-color: #4CAF50; 
        color: white;
        padding: 32px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 60px;
        margin: 200px 100px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 250;
        height: 200;
    }
    .click1 {border-radius: 8px}
    .click1 {
        background-color: grey; 
        color: #070d0f; 
        border: 2px solid #070d0f;
    }
    
    .click1:hover {
        background-color: #070d0f;
        color: white;
    }
    .click2 {border-radius: 8px}
    .click2 {
        background-color: grey; 
        color: #070d0f; 
        border: 2px solid #070d0f;
    }
    
    .click2:hover {
        background-color: #070d0f;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .click3 {border-radius: 8px}
    .click3 {
        background-color: grey; 
        color: #070d0f; 
        border: 2px solid #070d0f;
    }
    
    .click3:hover {
        background-color: #070d0f;
        color: white;
    }
    .click5 {border-radius: 8px}
    .click5 {
        background-color: grey; 
        color: #070d0f; 
        border: 2px solid #070d0f;
    }
    
    .click5:hover {
        background-color: #070d0f;
        color: white;
    }
    .click10 {border-radius: 8px}
    .click10 {
        background-color: grey; 
        color: #070d0f; 
        border: 2px solid #070d0f;
    }
    
    .click10:hover {
        background-color: #070d0f;
        color: white;
    }
    
        footer {
        color: grey;
        font-size: 65px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
      <title>Button of Magnificance</title>
      <body>
        <center>
          <button class="button click1">+1</button>
          <button class="button click2">+2</button>
          <button class="button click2">+3</button>
          <button class="button click5">+5</button>
          <button class="button click10">+10</button>
        </center>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hi there, consider using the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) for saving values attached to each buttons in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of code making what you want. I commented the JS part so that you can understand it but dont hesitate to ask if you still have questions.

```
<html>
<title>Button of Magnificance</title>
<body>
<style>
body{
    background-color: #162428;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; 
    color: white;
    padding: 32px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 100px 100px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 250;
    height: 200;
}
.click1 {border-radius: 8px}
.click1 {
    background-color: grey; 
    color: #070d0f; 
    border: 2px solid #070d0f;
}

.click1:hover {
    background-color: #070d0f;
    color: white;
}
.click2 {border-radius: 8px}
.click2 {
    background-color: grey; 
    color: #070d0f; 
    border: 2px solid #070d0f;
}

.click2:hover {
    background-color: #070d0f;
    color: white;
}

.click3 {border-radius: 8px}
.click3 {
    background-color: grey; 
    color: #070d0f; 
    border: 2px solid #070d0f;
}

.click3:hover {
    background-color: #070d0f;
    color: white;
}
.click5 {border-radius: 8px}
.click5 {
    background-color: grey; 
    color: #070d0f; 
    border: 2px solid #070d0f;
}

.click5:hover {
    background-color: #070d0f;
    color: white;
}
.click10 {border-radius: 8px}
.click10 {
    background-color: grey; 
    color: #070d0f; 
    border: 2px solid #070d0f;
}

.click10:hover {
    background-color: #070d0f;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<center>
<button class="button click1" data-value="1">+1</button>
<button class="button click2" data-value="2">+2</button>
<button class="button click2" data-value="3">+3</button>
<button class="button click5" data-value="5">+5</button>
<button class="button click10" data-value="10">+10</button>
<h1 style="color: #FFF;">
    count : <span class="count">0</span>
</h1>
</center>

<!-- Import JQuery -->
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // start script when DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // initialize a counter to 0
        var count = 0;
        // do something when an element with "button" class is clicked
        $('.button').on('click', function(){
            // get the button value
            var value = $(this).data('value');
            // update the count with new value
            count += value;
            // print the new value count on the element with "count" class
            $('.count').html(count);
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
<style>
footer {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 65px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I just need to add the web storage, but besides that, thank you a ton!

Comment: Kevinniel, do you know how to add web storage to this? Specifically Local Storage?

Comment: Yes i do, but what do you need exactly ? And now you have a base, it shouldn't be too hard for you to check at `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()` functions ;p

Comment: Where would I set these codes, would it go in a new script under all the current ones, before them, or in one of them?

Comment: You can make it in the same script area. Between my differents line of code. What do you wanna store exactly ? only the count value ?

Comment: Yes. In case I accidentally refresh or the web browser crashes I want the value to still be there.

Comment: Would that be possible with local storage? I think it should, right?

Comment: Hey, I'm still struggling with the localstorage, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JS like this

```
var count=0;
function updateValue(val){
    count = count + val;
}
```

and in every button you have created, you may add an onclick to call this function, as follows:

```
<button class="button click1" onclick="updateValue(1)">+1</button>
<button class="button click2" onclick="updateValue(2)">+2</button>
```

**To store the value** in cache you may use **localStorage**.
You can read about them here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

### Notes

This answer is using the [ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla). Be sure to be confortable with this one before going any further.

### Explainations

You can achieve what you want by using a class on your button to identify buttons that must be incremented buttons.

Using a `getElementsByClassName()` will help you retrieve only buttons that match the class you gave in your HTML.

Then, you need to iterate through your buttons. I use the newer spread operator to transform your `HTMLCollection` into an `Array`. You can then use the `forEach` method to operate a set of instructions (set the HTML content and add a listener) for each one of the buttons.

Using the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) and some application logic will ensure that data are kept from reloading the page.

### Code

HTML:

```
<button class='button-counter'></button>
<button class='button-counter'></button>
<button class='button-counter' data-count='5'></button>
```

Javascript:

```
'use strict';

// all the .button-counter from the DOM
const buttonsCounter = document.getElementsByClassName('button-counter');

// sets the content of the button to what value is currently set for data-counter
const buttonCounterSetText = button => button.innerHTML = `Click me (${button.dataset.count || 0})`;

// handles click event on the button
const buttonCounterClickHandler = ({currentTarget}) => {
  // increases the current value for data-count, or sets it to 0
  currentTarget.dataset.count = (parseInt(currentTarget.dataset.count) || 0) + 1;
  // see above
  buttonCounterSetText(event.currentTarget);
}; 

// initialize the buttons content and add listeners for click events
const buttonCounterInitialization = button => {
  buttonCounterSetText(button);
  button.addEventListener('click', buttonCounterClickHandler);
};

// initialize all buttons found with class .button-counter
[...buttonsCounter].forEach(buttonCounterInitialization);
```

### Demo

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrpEEm?editors=0010).